# the method toString(long) in the type Long is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Tags: string, tostring

I am getting compile time error while converting already set model class object into string in my project. In the AlmUserVO class ICA was set to long.

```
    **String temp = Long.toString(almUserVO.setIca(0));**
```

tried with below alternate 
**long l= almUserVO.setIca(0);
String temp= String.valueOf(l);**

Comment: after trying with 2nd option(i.e l**ong l= almUserVO.setIca(0); String temp= String.valueOf(l);**) getting compile error for  **Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to long**

Comment: Your setter is returning void, as setters should. Just use `0`. Or `getIca()`.